# php cURL - POST Not working

Tags: php, post, curl

Trying some simple code to work with cURL but no lucky..
I tried to POST a form but nothing happens and no error occurs.

Here is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost:8888/curl/home2.php');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'usuario=teste&senha=12345');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$store = curl_exec ($ch);

print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
echo curl_errno($ch) . '-' . 
                curl_error($ch);

echo $store;
```

When submit happens on the form home2.php it should go to another page and return some data. Am i doing something wrong?

**--- UPDATE**

Here is my simple home2.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="login.php" id="formLogin" name="formLogin">
        Usuario <input name="login" type="text">
        Senha <input name="senha" type="text">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

login.php :

```
<?php

$login = $_POST['login'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

if($login == "teste"){
    echo "OK";
}

?>
```

It should be "OK" as my result, right?

Comment: It looks OK for this code. Can you show that full code including home2.php?

Comment: Try to add these 2 lines before curl_exec `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);`

Comment: @spicydog Done. Updated the post.

Comment: @Mihai Same thing :(

Comment: Your error seems fairly obvious. You're sending the curl request with a "username" key named `usuario`, but your form is expecting `login`. You also need to submit towards `login.php` and not `home2.php`. What actually happens when you submit the form on `home2.php` through a browser is that the browser sends the form input to `login.php` - it never gets sent to `home2.php`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Oh, thank you! So, if when i pass the login form and want to do another POST request, i also have to target my URL with the next form action? Not URL page? Example: Home2.php (form: login.php) > Sucess.php (form: search.php). In my cURL definition i have to set login.php and the next as search.php. Right?

Comment: Completely correct - you have to completely emulate what a browser would do. If in doubt, which includes several different requests. Your cookie-jar will make sure that the several requests keep the logged in state. Software like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) (or any other HTTP packet sniffer) or the network tab in your browser will do wonders of telling you exactly what requests it's making.

Comment: That's awesome, thank you! If you put these comments as a answer i will vote as correct, so people can see better.

Comment: @ziad.ali You're very welcome - I've added it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form on `home2.php` looks like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="login.php" id="formLogin" name="formLogin">
    Usuario <input name="login" type="text">
    Senha <input name="senha" type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

It's important to note that the username input box is named `login`, yet when you create the cURL request, you're sending the username as `usario`. This needs to be changed. You also need to emulate what a browser would do and send the post variables towards `login.php` (`action="login.php"`) instead of `home2.php` (this page *only* includes the form, and never receives any of the input form data).

All in all, your code should be fixable by:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost:8888/curl/login.php');
// Change the URL                                         ^^^^^
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'login=teste&senha=12345');
// Change the username key             ^^^^^
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$store = curl_exec ($ch);

print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
echo curl_errno($ch) . '-' . 
                curl_error($ch);

echo $store;
```

If you're ever in doubt, the network tab in your browser (or any HTTP packet sniffer) will tell you exactly what requests the browser makes, with what variables, towards what URLs, and you'll be able to replicate it way easier.

**Note**: If your `success.php` page that `login.php` apparently redirects to on success does anything at all, you'll also need to have this be called automatically.

If `login.php` automatically redirects, you can just use the cURL option `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` set to 1.

Comment: It worked. So i'm trying to do with some site that i need and it's not mine (Not localhost). But am facing an problem that also don't POST and i'm using the right name as my input. What changes is the form point to something like that: index.php#tabs-1. And even if i set this to my URL, the POST do not happen. Do you think i should open another Question to be more specific?

Comment: If the only difference is the hashtag, then there's some javascript fiddling going on. Use an HTTP sniffer to see what requests the site is making when clicking on the button you want to emulate.

Comment: Using what you said and going to the view source i found it. It was a hidden field. Now it's working. - Sorry to keep bothering you but what if I want to make like a 100 requests each time and grab the returned data. Easy task? I mean, the result is a full webpage and i want part of the fields. I don't know what to search.. "cURL grab data"? @h2ooooooo

Comment: You're looking for a "web scraper" or a "dom parser". Essentially you'd want to search for "php web scraper" or "php dom parser". I like to use [`simplehtmldom`](https://github.com/sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser) to give me a jQuery like search-and-collect. [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) is also quite decent.

Comment: I have to use as a complement to what i've done, right? Please say yes. Because i saw an usage like: "$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');" and got scared. I can use like html = file_get_html($store);  ?

Comment: What I tend to do is fetch the body with cURL (as you've already done) and then used `str_get_html`. `file_get_html` is just a quick-wrapper if you literally don't care about cURL at all. [Here's the simplehtmldom documentation - please note that it's sourceforge, so you *might* get a virus error if you're using firefox, even though it's just a manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm).

Comment: Oh, never had to deal with DOM objects. I pass as a parameter to str_get_html my return of curl and them start to use the command "find" to get what i want. As i said before, i have to do like 100 request each time, so i keep my curl login open and make a loop to post the second form and create a DOM each result and grab the data with find, right? Will try that @h2ooooooo, thank you!

Comment: @ziad.ali Yep, that would be the way to do it, though it won't be super fast, and the site might block you if you do this too often. If so, you can always use `sleep` or `usleep` to slow down a bit :)

Comment: I started to use the simple DOM. As you are more experienced in this technology than me, if you still around and want to take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31642634/php-simple-html-dom-parser-table-issue. Apparently what i received from the cURL come with an <span> in a table am wanting to get the results.. Wondering if you know how to automatically remove that.. @h2ooooooo

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned "When submit happens on the form home2.php it should go to another page". By that do you mean that there is an HTTP redirect? If so, you need to tell cURL to follow redirects. Like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Comment: When submit happens it should go to login.php as set in the action form in home2.php. I updated the post with full code. Also tried what you suggested but still the same. @Asaph