# PHP - Simple HTML DOM Parser - Table Issue

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

I'm receiving some data from cURL and want to grab informations so i can save in another database.

The result of the cURL is a hole html page, so i'm using Simple HTML DOM Parser to get what i want. The problem is, i want the values of a table, but i'm getting just the tittles.

Here's the page:

```
<div id="conteudo">
<body>
<div id="tab">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-a">Test1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-b">Test2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-c">Test3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tabs-1">
  <div>
  <table id="d1" name="d1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td width="15%">Name:</td><td>
        <form method="POST" id="form" action="index.php#tabs-1" >
              <input name="txtName" type="text">
              <input name="btn" value="ok" id="btn" type="submit">
        </form>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name:</td>
      <td><b>John</b></td>
      <td>Age:</td>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Father:</td>
      <td>Locke</td>
      <td>Mother:</td>
      <td>Felicity</span>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adress:</td>
      <td>Ok</td>
      <td>City:</td>
      <td>New York</td>
    </tr>
  </table> 

...
```

What i'm trying:

```
$table = $html->find('table', 4);
$rowData = array();

foreach($table->find('tr') as $row) {
    // initialize array to store the cell data from each row
    $flight = array();
    foreach($row->find('td') as $cell) {
        // push the cell's text to the array
        $flight[] = $cell->plaintext;
    }
    $rowData[] = $flight;
}

echo '<table>';
foreach ($rowData as $row => $tr) {
    echo '<tr>'; 
    foreach ($tr as $td)
        echo '<td>' . $td .'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

What i'm getting:

```
Name:
Father:
Mother:
```

The problem is, i'm not getting the whole data.. Just the tittles, can you see?

Comment: Whats the source code to the html class in php?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what you are requesting. Isn't the first source code i post it?

Comment: I mean your code refers to a class named html and you don't have the source code to that class shown.

Comment: The $html? That's the result of cURL(Hole page). And the first source code is the part of $html that i want.

Comment: @Mike that's from using simple_html_dom's `file_get_html` or `str_get_html`

Comment: @ziad.ali where is your data coming from?